# string difference in jsondiffpatch nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am using `jsondiffpatch` npm module for the difference.

left JSON contains

```
"inclusionParams": "{\"internalCode\":{\"isIncluded\":true,\"type\":\"string\",\"searchStr\":\"320150,320285,321887,322866,322867,323007,323009,323011,323037,323051,323907,323914\"}}",
```

right JSON contains

```
"inclusionParams": "{\"country\":{\"isIncluded\":true,\"type\":\"string\",\"searchStr\":\"US\",\"expr\":null,\"ids\":null},\"ext.dmaCode\":{\"isIncluded\":false,\"type\":\"string\",\"searchStr\":\"868, 801, 641, 597, 504\",\"expr\":null,\"ids\":null},\"status\":{\"isIncluded\":true,\"type\":\"string\",\"searchStr\":\"Active\",\"expr\":null,\"ids\":null}}",
```

getting difference something like

```
inclusionParams=["@@ -80,76 +80,32 @@\n ,855\n-,%22%7D,%22status%22:%7B%22isIncluded%22:true,%22type%22:%22string%22,%22searchStr%22:%22Active%22\n+%22,%22expr%22:null,%22ids%22:null\n %7D,%22c\n@@ -163,10 +163,33 @@\n tr%22:%22US%22\n+,%22expr%22:null,%22ids%22:null\n %7D%7D\n",0,2];
```

but I want to get the difference as of right JSON value instead of the above value[character wise difference].
how to achieve it?
are there any configurations?

Answer (score 0):

```
 differ = jsondiffpatch.create({
    textDiff: {
    // default 60, minimum string length (left and right sides) to use text diff algorythm: google-diff-match-patch
    minLength: 10000
},
});
```